# Embedded Tomcat in spring boot blocking some keywords

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

We are facing some issue with our spring boot application. we are using Embedded tomcat. when we hit couple of urls with the keywords having special characters, its not reaching our application. The application is hosted in google cloud. We are unable to reproduce this on local, but when he hit the same url in other environments , we can see the blank page. We checked by adding lot of logs in filters and our controllers, the request is not coming to our application it self. Can somebody help me with this issue.

```
Example: www.test.com/s/5%2F8%20spark%20plug
```

Comment: That `%2F` looks like it could be a problem, especially if there is an intermediary (router, proxy, or so on) interpreting the URL.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Is there a way that we can ask tomcat to allow these keywords? Thanks !!

Comment: It's not a keyword, it's weird URL encoding, and it's almost certainly upstream of Tomcat--the GCE router, for example.

Answer (score 0):

as @chrylis mentioned, there isn't anything that you can do in your application to allow this type of URL to work, as the problem is before your application, and your application never gets the request.

I recommend that instead of spending a lot of time investigating why the Google Cloud platform is choking on the URLs, you take a hard look at your application and ask yourself if you really need these 'nonstandard' urls.

If,  for instance, "5%2F8%20spark%20plug" is something provided by an end-user (or a url-encoded version of something provided by an end-user), then perhaps it would be better to use an id (a Long or a UUID) instead - something that is "normalized" and known to not create a URL-parsing issue.